# Count unique number of string based on condition in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to count unique strings based on condition in excel.

In the example below, column `B` to `F` are inputs and columns `G` and `H` is **expected output**.

Currently I am using formula for `H6` `=COUNTIFS(E1:E20, "<>", B1:B20, G6, C1:C20, "v1", D1:D20, "f")`
But with this formula `1` is counted `2` times, but I don't want to count duplicate entries.

[image: Sample sheet image]

How can I ignore duplicates and count only distinct values based on condition?

Comment: If column A is part of your inputs, there will be no duplicates

Comment: Column `A` is not part of input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `H6`, array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) copied down :

```
=SUM(N(FREQUENCY(IF(($B$1:$B$20=G6)*($C$1:$C$20="V1")*($D$1:$D$20="f"),$E$1:$E$20),$E$1:$E$20)>0))
```

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it by 2 minutes!

Comment: It works perfectly.. Thanks for the help. Also can I avoid Ctrl+Shift+Enter for updating the value in cell?

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 2016+ with the `UNIQUE` function, you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX(UNIQUE(input_arr),,1)=G6)*(INDEX(UNIQUE(input_arr),,2)="v1")*(INDEX(UNIQUE(input_arr),,3)="f")*(INDEX(UNIQUE(input_arr),,4)<>""))
```

where `input_arr` refers to `=$B$1:$E$20`

[image]

If you have an earlier version of Excel, I would suggest

- Copy original data to a new location
- Select the entire table, then "Remove Duplicates" ensuring all columns are selected
- If new table is, for example, in B37:E37, use the formula:

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INDEX($B$27:$E$37,,1)=G6)*(INDEX($B$27:$E$37,,2)="v1")*(INDEX($B$27:$E$37,,3)="f")*(INDEX($B$27:$E$37,,4)<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: I am using excel 2013
`UNIQUE` is not working for me

Comment: The count value should be updated dynamically.. So I cannot copy and count unique values